# Convert byte[] to VideoFrame or VideoFrame.I420Buffer WebRtc class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, video, webrtc

Is there any method to convert byte[] NV21Data to WebRtc VideoFrame ?

I try to do it with `TextureBufferImpl` and seems its the only way, but it looks really complex.

```
YuvConverter yuvConverter = new YuvConverter(); 
TextureBufferImpl buffer = new TextureBufferImpl(composedBitmap.getWidth(), 
composedBitmap.getHeight(),VideoFrame.TextureBuffer.Type.RGB, 
textures[0], new Matrix(), surfaceTextureHelper.getHandler(), yuvConverter, null);


VideoFrame.I420Buffer i420Buf = yuvConverter.convert(buffer);
VideoFrame CONVERTED_FRAME = new VideoFrame(i420Buf, 0, System.nanoTime());
```

This question has info how to convert VideoFrame to byte[]
[Android org.webrtc.VideoRenderer.I420Frame arrays to PreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803423/android-org-webrtc-videorenderer-i420frame-arrays-to-previewcallback-onpreviewfr)

This way gives VideoFrame as black, seems not working as intended.

This question is converting to webRtc VideoFrame from surface
[Converting a Bitmap to a WebRTC VideoFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494654/converting-a-bitmap-to-a-webrtc-videoframe)

https://gist.github.com/n1xx1/2cd38043838e259969bce983ce21ffaa

Comment: I faced frame black issue..  can you give solution for this ? I offered bounty for this question also (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494654/converting-a-bitmap-to-a-webrtc-videoframe)

Comment: any update on this?